# Plugin for Eclipseplugin, how to manage dependency?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I have the following setup: i have a eclipseplugin A. Then there are two plugins B & C that extend the features of A, so B and C are plugins for A.

Currently if somebody only installs B, the menu entires etc. that A creates are not avalible. Therefore the user can not access the features of B.

My Question now is, is there any way to either:

- Abort the installation of B/C if A is not installed with a corresponding error msg?
- Or automatically install A if the user tries to install B?

I hope my explanations make any kind of sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(What is unclear is how you are installing the plug-ins as you have to go through extra effort to install B without A if B is dependent on A)

> Or automatically install A if the user tries to install B?

This is your best bet. This is the way the Eclipse works by default. Make feature.xmls for the A, B and C plugins (or what will become groups of interrelated plugins). Place them on a P2 site and let users install whichever feature they want. If they select B, A will automatically be installed because of the dependencies described in the feature xmls.

Comment: Using a p2 updatesite to install my plugins. Thanks for your answer, I will look into it later today. The plugins are on different p2 sites, but that shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: If all the p2 sites are in the "Available Software Sites" list then no problem. If a user tries to install B, and either  "Available Software Sites" does not have location of A or user has manually deselected "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" then they will be presented with an error and will not be able to install.

Comment: PS. I wanted to make sure you knew about Composite P2 Repos  https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Composite_Repositories_(new) that allows all of A, B and C to be on one URL, but still have them be different update sites.

Comment: okay i fixed it :-) I was importing the plugins i needed from A, not the feature. I added the UI-feature and it works like a charm now. EDIT: composite repos seems like a good solution for me, will look into it